# VC++ vector::push_back "Access Violation" in DLL

Tags: c++, exception, vector, dll, access-violation

I try to transform a Win32 Application into a DLL. But I've got some difficulties with STL vector. In original application all works fine, but in DLL "Access violation reading location" error occures. Here's the code of .h

```
    #ifdef NNETDLL_EXPORTS
    #define NNETDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define NNETDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif

    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;
    #define VECARRAY vector<double>

    class NNETDLL_API CNNetDll 
    {
    public:
        CNNetDll(void);
        virtual ~CNNetDll();

        int m_InputNeurons, m_HiddenNeurons, m_OutputNeurons;

        /* Активаторы */
        vector<double> inputs;
        vector<double> hidden;
        vector<double> actual;

        /* Вход скрытых ячеек(со смещением) */
        vector<VECARRAY> who;

        /* Вход выходных ячеек(со смещением) */
        vector<VECARRAY> wih;

        int InitializeNetwork(CString FileName);
        void feedForward();
        void ActionNN(/*VECARRAY input_vec, VECARRAY& output_vec*/);
        void ReadNN(CString FileName);
    };
```

And here's the code of .cpp, where an exception occures

```
int CNNetDll::InitializeNetwork(CString FileName)
{
    int i, hid, inp, out;
    CFile f;
    CString s;
    TCHAR szDrive[200];
    TCHAR szDir[200];
    TCHAR szFile[200];
    TCHAR szExt[200];

    _wsplitpath_s(FileName, szDrive, szDir, szFile, szExt);
    SetCurrentDirectory(szDir);
    s = szExt;  FileName = szFile + s;

    f.Open(FileName, CFile::modeRead);
    f.Read(&m_InputNeurons, sizeof(double));
    f.Read(&m_HiddenNeurons, sizeof(double));
    f.Read(&m_OutputNeurons, sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < m_InputNeurons; i++)
    {
        inputs.push_back(0.0); // !!!!! ERROR IS HERE !!!!!!
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m_HiddenNeurons; i++)
    {
        hidden.push_back(0.0);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m_OutputNeurons; i++)
    {
        actual.push_back(0.0);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m_HiddenNeurons + 1; i++)
    {
        who.push_back(actual);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m_InputNeurons + 1; i++)
    {
        wih.push_back(hidden);
    }
    for (hid = 0; hid < m_HiddenNeurons; hid++)
    {
        for (inp = 0; inp <= m_InputNeurons; inp++)
        {
            f.Read(&wih[inp][hid], sizeof(double));
        }
    }
    for (out = 0; out < m_OutputNeurons; out++)
    {
        for (hid = 0; hid <= m_HiddenNeurons; hid++)
        {
            f.Read(&who[hid][out], sizeof(double));
        }
    }

    f.Close();

    return 1;
}
```

The app falls trying to fill the vector. The last step in callstack is in "xutility" file on this lines:

```
inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all()
    {   // orphan all iterators
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    if (_Myproxy != 0)
        {   // proxy allocated, drain it
        _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);

        for (_Iterator_base12 **_Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
            *_Pnext != 0; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter) // !!!!LAST OPERATION BEFORE EXCEPTION!!!
            (*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = 0;
        _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = 0;
        }
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
    }
```

Repeating, in original application everithing works fine. Also I notice, that the error arises with that vector, which declaration goes first in CNNetDll class. In above code it's vector "inputs". If I change declarations like this

```
vector<double> hidden;
vector<double> actual;
vector<double> inputs;
```

then the exception arises with vector "hidden" on this code

```
for (i = 0; i < m_InputNeurons; i++)
{
    inputs.push_back(0.0); //!!!! works properly !!!!!
}
for (i = 0; i < m_HiddenNeurons; i++)
{
    hidden.push_back(0.0); // !!! exception here !!!
}
for (i = 0; i < m_OutputNeurons; i++)
{
    actual.push_back(0.0);
}
```

Оbject creation and function call:

```
CNNetDll nn;
nn.InitializeNetwork(_T("M:\\Tasks\\2016\\Win8-64\\AI\\NNet\\Debug\\NN.dat"));
```

How to solve this problem????

Comment: You have defined m_InputNeurons, m_HiddenNeurons, m_OutputNeurons as int data type but storing the size of double data type to it. This will cause invalid memory access. Change f.Read(&m_InputNeurons, sizeof(double)); to f.Read(&m_InputNeurons, sizeof(int)); in all of the three f.Read or change the data type of m_InputNeurons etc to double.

Comment: Can't believe the problem was there in such simple thing, but now it works. Thanks. Strange that it works perfectly in .exe application and in dll fails.

Comment: Such things happens in C++ with raw memory operations. The three `f.Read()` calls will overwrite beyond the size of `int` data type and it might corrupt other member variables such as `inputs` so when call to `inputs.push_back(0.0);` is made, it causes access violation. Access violation error might not occur exactly at the point of memory overwrite, it may happen at a later point of execution and that is what happened in this case.

Comment: It might work in an executable because the overwritten area wouldn't have executed/encountered so far. This kind of behaviour can also happen when a program is run with Debug version of exe/dll which contains debug guard bytes. In this case, the it would be the guard bytes which will be overwritten and it will not cause access violation in Debug build but it will happen in Release build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in wrong variables definition(with int data type) and storing the size of double data type to these variables.With matching types all works perfectly.

```
int m_InputNeurons, m_HiddenNeurons, m_OutputNeurons;
```